# PHP Imagick Problems with Composite / Colorchannel

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick, imagick

I have a picture, where i want to set a color-channel to black. In PHP Imagick, i'm reading the image, create a black image and create a composite with "COMPOSITE_COPYGREEN" in "CHANNEL_GREEN".

Unfortunately on my linux-machine (PHP 7.2), everything works fine. On my Windows, the image becomes black.

Different Imagick Versions
Different Windows machines

```
$file = new Imagick();
$file->readImage("....");
$file->setImageFormat('png');
$file->setImageColorspace (Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

$blackImage = new Imagick();
$blackImage->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('black'));
$blackImage->setImageColorspace (Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$blackImage->setImageFormat("png");

$file->compositeImage($blackImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYGREEN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN);

...
```

On Linux (PHP 7.2) everything works fine, on windows, the image is black.

Comment: Likely an issue with the Windows version that cannot be fixed without an update. But check to see if you have the same versions of ImageMagick. If not, just update ImageMagick without changing Imagick.